# Java parse error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm learning Java and I'm working on class constructors. When I go to compile the code for the example I get an error: *Your code did not compile: /TestGame.java:35: reached end of file while parsing     }*

Here is my code:

```
public class Game {
    int homeScore;
    int visitorScore;

    //add your default constructor here

    public Game() {
        this.homeScore = 0;
        this.visitorScore = 0;
    }

    public boolean isHomeWinner() {
        return homeScore > visitorScore;
    }

    public boolean isVisitorWinner() {
        return homeScore < visitorScore;
    }

    public boolean isTie() {
        return homeScore == visitorScore;
    }
}
```

I researched online and saw that this is usually created by not having a closing brace or a quote, but everything looks closed to me.

What else can cause this error?

Comment: It seems to compile just fine over here. Sure that's the only thing you're trying to compile?

Comment: Is your class called Game, but the file called TestGame.java? Both need to be called the same thing. If your class is Game, then the file it is in has to be called Game.java.

Comment: Please provide the class TestGame.java

Comment: Looks like your class is called Game but the file is called TestGame? This cant be . Other than that cant see anything wrong.

Comment: Although I don't think that would cause the error OP is seeing.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard yes it is, i've tried :P

Comment: @javi What compiler? I get (and expect) "class Game is public, should be declared in a file named Game.java".

Comment: So the point is, we're missing some other code which we'd need to see in order to find the problem. Most likely, you're just missing a closing bracket `}` somewhere.

Comment: @Daniel I use NetBeans. I didn't get the exact error as OP but in fact I think is the same error. If you change the name to Game.java everything goes perfectly.

Comment: It's an online "compiler" that comes with where I'm taking the lessons from. What I have provided is everything that I enter into the field online, and it compiles, so I don't have access to the class TestGame.java. I'm assuming that's somewhere behind the scenes.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Don't know where line 35 is, I stuck this in Notepad++ and it's note even 35 lines long.....

Comment: Yeah, your code looks fine, so unfortunately it looks like the error is on "their" side.